# how to create a "visibleWhen" for org.eclispe.ui.newWizards?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I build some menus by "org/eclipse/ui/newWizards", but i can't build "command" for it. 
I want something like "visibleWhen" to command my newWizards.
How can i do?
First question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the visibility of New Wizards, all wizards are shown in the dialog all of the time.

Comment: thanks for your help.I just want to control the newWizards for my Eclipse-plugin

Comment: and how to build this function like the "menus" extention?

Comment: when my i select project A it show newA, if select B show B in the file-new.

Comment: You can't do that in File > New.

Comment: I know, i mean how to use other extensions to achieve it.just like a custom File > New.You know Eclipse's File > New can  auto adapter when we change the selections.